# Saving core data or save backend db, which should be done first?

Tags: ios, http, core-data, request, alamofire

I'm new to ios dev (or mobile client dev in general). I have backend db which needs to be updated everytime my model is updated from client. I also save data in core data for offline / caching.

I'm wondering if you can guide me to the best practices when it comes to updating the core data and backend data. Right now what I do is I send http request using Alamofire and in the success callback I then update core data, client then reloads core data to show that update is completed. But this seems kind of not efficient since I have to wait until request has been completed. On the other hand, If I just go ahead and update core data and update backend data in the background after displaying results to user, the request may fail...

Answer (score 0):

Store a `lastChanged` and a `lastSynchronised` date on each object. `lastChanged` is updated whenever you make a change to a synchronised object. `lastSynchronised` is updated on success response from the server.

Now, when you make a change you know if it's synchronised or not, so whether it's becoming dirty or it's another update to an already dirty object.

When you have an internet connection you can find all dirty objects and try to synchronise them.

The only complexity is updates being applied while a synchronisation is in progress. You need to take care that you don't have an object which should be dirty but is marked as synchronised. This could be done by 'locking' the object during synchronisation, or it could be done by comparing the server response with the object on success to verify a match.